# Trouble playing an MP3 file in python via Pyglet

Tags: python, audio, mp3, pyglet

Summary: (Trying to play MP3 in python via pyglet library, AVbin not detected, Mp3 not played)

So i'm trying to to play an MP3 file in python with pyglet. i installed pyglet with the command prompt and all that good stuff, and I went to the AVbin website and downloaded and ran their .exe file. Im not sure if just running the .exe file actually installs AVbin, but that's all ive done with it so far. So my problem is im trying to play an mp3 that i have located on my desktop, but Pyglet still doesnt recognize AVbin? Here's the code as well as the error message:

Code:

```
import pyglet

music = pyglet.media.load(r"C:\Users\Doug\Desktop\01 Gem Shards - 4A.mp3")
music.play()

pyglet.app.run()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python34/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    music = pyglet.media.load(r"C:\Users\Doug\Desktop\01 Gem Shards - 4A.mp3")
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyglet-1.2.3a1-py3.4.egg\pyglet\media\__init__.py", line 1429, in load
    source = get_source_loader().load(filename, file)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyglet-1.2.3a1-py3.4.egg\pyglet\media\__init__.py", line 1410, in load
    return riff.WaveSource(filename, file)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pyglet-1.2.3a1-py3.4.egg\pyglet\media\riff.py", line 201, in __init__
    'AVbin is required to decode compressed media')
pyglet.media.riff.WAVEFormatException: AVbin is required to decode compressed media
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add AvBin to your PATH enviroment variable:

you can do this with the folowwing command

```
setx path "%path%;c:\pathToAvBin"
```

plase note that you need to change "c:\pathToAvBin" for your real path to av bin :)

**BE CAREFULL TO NOT CLEAR YOUR PATH**

Comment: I wrote it down as such and it gave me a syntax error?
setx path "%path%;C:\Windows\System32\avbin64.dll"

Comment: try to follow these steps http://www.howtogeek.com/118594/how-to-edit-your-system-path-for-easy-command-line-access/

Comment: Ok i added the file path to the system environment variable, do i need to type something in the cmd?

Comment: no, just open a new cmd and try to call your python script

Comment: So AVbin can only play mp3s when python is launched via the cmd? also im not sure how to call the script T_T

Comment: no, you should be able to call it just double clicking the script. What happens when you try thisk approach?

Comment: I moved the script to the desktop and opened it. the cmd appears for a split second and then disappears, no sound is played. im hoping to implement the audio player in with a gui so im not keen on running straight from cmd.